# http 415 error in cxf rest service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, apache-camel

I am trying to build some rest and soap services using camel cxf-rs module. Soap part is fine, in rest part i have one GET and one POST methods with following signature. GET method working fine but POST method(which expects a customer json object ) get HTTP status of 415 with error "No message body reader has been found for class".Can anybody tell what is missing here ?

Rest interface:

```
@WebService
@Path("/bookstore")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public interface BookStore {

    @WebMethod
    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes("*/*")
    Book getBook(@PathParam("id") @WebParam(name = "id") Long id) throws Exception;

    @WebMethod
    @POST
    @Path("/books")
    Book addBook(@WebParam(name = "book") Book book);

}
```

PS: Here is the sample curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"xyz","isbn":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8080/api/servlet/rest/bookstore/books
```

Comment: How did you place the call to POST ? please show us the curl command that you're using